# Count rows of attribute table of a shapefile in ArcGIS with Python

Tags: arcpy, python

I need to count the rows of a certain selection of the attribute table of a shapefile. I am very new to Python and have never executed it in ArcGIS.

When I run this code in the Python console of ArcMap

```
import arcpy


table = "C:/path/name.shp"
cursor = db.cursor()
count = cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + str(table) "where y = 0 and x = 0")
db.commit()
print cursor.fetchone()[0]
cursor.close()
```

I get the error `Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 5)`

If I run

```
import arcpy


table = "H:/Bearbeitung IS_SaND/Kartenbearbeitung/Kartendaten/mas_p.shp"
cursor = db.cursor()
count = cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s where y = 0 and x = 0" + str(table))
db.commit()
print cursor.fetchone()[0]
cursor.close()
```

I get error

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
NameError: name 'db' is not defined
```

How can I fix my code?

Comment: There are better ways to count features, and better ways to interact with a shapefile than using a database cursor. You don't ever declare (or `import`, I suspect) the code for the `db` variable, whic makes the posted question a pure Python issue.

Comment: Cross-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/q/43848377/820534

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the [GetCount](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm) tool:

```
table =  "path to table"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(table, "myfeatures")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("myfeatures", "NEW_SELECTION", "Y=0 and X=0")
result  = arcpy.GetCount_management("myfeatures")
print(result.getOutput(0))
```

You're trying to use some (maybe) python module, `db`. It hasn't been imported in your code, so you wont be able to run it. It looks more like you're trying to use syntax from another software package, database or maybe even SQL with arcpy -- you can't simply interchange it like that.

As of **ArcGIS Pro 2.3**, both the Select Layer by Attribute and Select Layer by Location tools have added a **count** output parameter. This parameter can be used to get the selection count, without having to run the Get Count tool. For example:

```
result = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation("address", "INTERSECT", "aoi")
result[2].count
>> 72343
```

Note - Select by Location has *count* as the 3rd output (ie. result index 2, `r[2].count`) where Select by Attribute has *count* as the 2nd output (ie result index 1, `r[1].count`)

Comment: Thanks. How can I include the where statement `where y = 0 and x = 0`?

Comment: I just made an edit - you need to turn your shapefile on disk into a layer. After that you can run the Select Layer by Attribute tool to perform a selection. You may need to tweak the where clause

Comment: I now get the error `Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 4, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6435, in SelectLayerByAttribute     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression using SelectLayerByAttribute`

Comment: I tried out a couple of codes. This also does not work: `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("myfeatures", "NEW_SELECTION", 'WHERE "X" = 0 and "Y" = 0')
`

Comment: I'll ask a new question.

Comment: Put the Select statement in triple quotes: `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("myfeatures", "NEW_SELECTION", """x =0 AND y =0""")`